# Mailchimp Apache Error

Tags: java, android, apache, mailchimp

im working with mailchimp, my objetive is to send users to the list in the mailchimp, so i used a wrapper from ecwid [this one](https://github.com/Ecwid/maleorang)

So i did a method that send a test user to my list, i added my list id and my Api Key , but i have an error

this is my code

```
private void mailchimp(){

        MailchimpClient client = new MailchimpClient("MY_API_KEY");
        try {
            EditMemberMethod.CreateOrUpdate method = new EditMemberMethod.CreateOrUpdate("MY_LIST_ID", "vasya.pupkin@gmail.com");
            method.status = "subscribed";
            method.merge_fields = new MailchimpObject();
            method.merge_fields.mapping.put("FNAME", "Vasya");
            method.merge_fields.mapping.put("LNAME", "Pupkin");

        MemberInfo member = null;

            Log.e("mailchimpmember",""+member);

            member = client.execute(method);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MailchimpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The problem is when i reach this method i get this from Apache in my android monitor at line `MailchimpClient client = new MailchimpClient("MY_API_KEY");`

> No virtual method setConnectionManagerShared(Z)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder; in class Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder' appears in /data/app/com.myapp.app.debug-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes78.dex)
>                                                                                         at com.ecwid.maleorang.connector.HttpClientConnector.(HttpClientConnector.kt:71)

and this one

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;

im really struggling to get mailchimp running in my project, i cant find a good wrapper and dont know how to properly set it up

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this video tutorial about posting new members to MailChimp list

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TkRUi_vN12k

Or just try using Volley for the http requests